# EF4.4 how to set StoreWins on request, rather than separate refresh?

Tags: c#, caching, entity-framework-4

We have multiple bounded contexts, and sometimes need to force RefreshMode.StoreWins on our requests.

Currently we do this as a two step process:

```
// Run my query, this handles refreshing WRT adds/deletes from other dbContext
var myThings = dbContext.Set<MyThing>()
    .Where(x => x.blah)
    .ToList();

// Get all entities in the change tracker.... any of them might have changed...!
var allEntities = DataContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Select(c => c.Entity).ToList();

// Refresh all these entities, this handles refreshing WRT updates from other dbContext
(((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext).Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, allEntities);
```

This is necessary for correct function of our application.

However it's terribly inefficient - I KNOW that EF just went to the database to run my query, but due to some in-built default of RefreshMode.ClientWins, it chooses to keep its own copy in memory.

Can I set some global default of RefreshMode.StoreWins, or, can I indicate this on a per-request basis?

P.S. We must keep DbContexts for the lifetime of a given screen, we do not regenerate for each new request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, it appears the best way to do this in EF4 on a per-query basis is to use ObjectQuery instead of DbQuery, and set the MergeOption. It's clunky but does the job:

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;

var query = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<SomeModel>()
       .Where(x => x.Blah);

((ObjectQuery)query).MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;

return query.ToList();
```